# Como criar uma classe dentro da outra no C++?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos

Preciso criar uma classe dentro da outra no C++

Por exemplo:
Já tenho a classe Calculadora criada. Preciso inserir dentro dela a classe OperadorAritmetico. Como devo criar? Como vai ficar o arquivo cabeçalho .h e o fonte .cpp?

Alguém pra me dar uma força?

Valeu!

Comment: Por que precisa?

Comment: O enunciado do problema é esse:

Portanto criaremos uma nova classe chamada OperadorAritmetico que fará parte da classe Calculadora.
Da mesma forma, uma nova classe parte, chamada OperadorTrigonometrico poderá ser adicionada à classe Calculadora para fazer as futuras operações de cálculo do seno, coseno e tangente. 
Portanto a classe todo Calculadora terá dois objetos parte: o objeto do tipo OperadorAritmetico e o objeto do tipo OperadorTrigonometrico.

Comment: Pelo que está aí não é para criar uma classe dentro da outra. E na verdade o enunciado pede algo que não parece ser adequado, não sei o texto está um pouco estranho para afirmar. Sem um contexto específico eu diria que não é para fazer assim.

Answer (score 1):

Basta usar `class` dentro da `class`. Lembre-se que a visibilidade se aplica igual a qualquer outro método o variável da classe. No exemplo abaixo a classe `OperadorAritmetico` é privado.

```
// Calculadora HPP

class Calculadora {
  class OperadorAritmetico {
   public:
    int soma(int a, int b);
  };

  OperadorAritmetico operador;

 public:
  int soma(int a, int b);
};
```

No fonte não esqueça de colocar o caminho completo do método.

```
// Calculadora.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Calculadora.hpp"

int Calculadora::OperadorAritmetico::soma( int a, int b )
{
  return a+b;
}

int Calculadora::soma( int a, int b )
{
  return operador.soma( a, b );
}
```

Neste teste simples o método `soma` da `Calculadora` chama internamente o método `soma` do `OperadorAritmético`.

```
int main( void )
{
  Calculadora calc;
  std::cout << "3 + 5 = " << calc.soma( 3, 5 ) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda!!
Depois procurando com mais calma na apostila postada pelo prof, acabei achando o que eu queria, que era fazer composição forte ou fraca, conforme abaixo:

a) Composição forte e fraca na área privada:
class A {
private:
B b; // Forte
C *pC; // Fraca
public:
};